# Javascript XmlHttpRequest aka ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Why is ajax in javascript called XMLhttprequest? I mean what's so `xml` about the request and why wasn't it just called http request.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is it called XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067185/why-is-it-called-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: @abhishekkannojia Yes it is a duplicate. Didn't know of this question before asking and also it got the answers I was looking for. Thanks for reference